# Why does this query generate so much data?

Tags: sql, db2

Err I apologize for the title, but I forgot what its actually called in SQL lingo.

Thing is using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.col1, a.col2,a.col3,c.col1, c.col2

FROM table1 a

LEFT JOIN table2 c ON a.col1 = c.col3

WHERE a.col2 = '038CQH'
```

I get a result with around 56000 rows, but when I checked using:

`SELECT a.col1, a.col2,a.col3 FROM table1 a where a.col2='038CQH'`

I get only 4 rows.

Comment: Please describe what you think the relationship between table1 and table2 via table1.col1 = table.col3 is - e.g. one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many

Comment: its many to many, does that matter? I'm really confused as the same query returns only 4 rows on postgres T_T

Answer (score 2):

It is because your 4 records from table1 join to many records in table2 based on the records in table2 where col3 matches col1 from table1.  BTW - these are horrible column names.

Comment: err those are just for example purposes

Comment: Christopherous 5000 is right, you are getting the Cartesian product of the two tables.

Since you say there are 4 rows in table1, there must be 56000/4 rows in table2

Comment: maybe i am not just that versed on db2, because the same query in postgres returns only the 4 rows that i need. is there anything else i need to do to make it work for db2?

Comment: @lock look closely at the relationships and ensure you are joining on the right columns.  Also - I'm pretty sure postgres and db2 has the ANSI standard implementation of join syntax.  So if you are truly using the exact same query for both - either the schema or the data between the two is different

Answer (score 1):

its the left join (`left join` is actually `left outer join`).  It means - get all records from table1 and all the records from table2, but where a.col1 != c.col3, put nulls on all table2 columns.

Maybe an inner join is what you need?  it would only add the columns from table2 where a.col1 = c.col3

Comment: -1 Left join takes all the records from the first (left) table

Comment: @Christopherous 5000: I was less clear then I could be - I edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: i also used inner join and a similar query without joins, using only "where a.col2 = '038CQH' and a.col1 = c.col3"

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach - re-run your query:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2,a.col3 FROM table1 a where a.col2='038CQH'
```

Note down the four values of a.col1 returned as [a1], [a2], [a3] and [a4].

Then try running the following query against table2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.col1, c.col2
table2 c WHERE c.col3 IN ([a1], [a2], [a3], [a4])
```

(where [a1] etc have been replaced with the previously noted values.)